# Ubuntu Education

Tags: application-development

I'm Vishal Nagda from India. I've basic knowledge of Python & C programming language, and I want to develop Ubuntu applications & also wishes to join Ubuntu Community. So I want to ask you that what requirements and qualifications I needed to fulfill my wishes.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know *how to create an application*, or *how to publish my applications*?

Comment: Requirement is enthusiasm and willingness to learn new things